# Using the sum disturbance method, find a compact form of the following sums:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, summation-method

I tried to solve these two examples, but without success, could someone help me solve it because I got stuck on them and don't understand how to solve them.

Using the sum disturbance method, find a compact form of the following sums:
\begin{align}
&\textrm{(a)} &&\sum_{k=1}^n{(-1)^k \frac{k}{2^{k-1}}}\\
&\textrm{(b)} &&\sum_{k=1}^n{(1+k2^{k-1})^2}
\end{align}

> The disturbance method is sum $${s_{n+1} = a_{1} + a_2 + \dots + a_n + a_{n+1}}$$ 
>   expressed in two ways. The first is obvious: $$s_{n+1} = s_n + a_{n+1}.$$ The second is to present $s_{n+1}$ in form:
>   $$s_{n+1} = a_1 + f(s_n),$$ where f is a function. Then we get the
>   equality $$s_n + a_{n+1} = a_1 + f(s_n).$$ This equality can be
>   treated as an equation with one unknown $s_n$. When it is solved in
>   relation to this unknown, we obtain a compact form of a sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (a),
\begin{align}
f(s_n)
&=s_{n+1}-a_1\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}{(-1)^k \frac{k}{2^{k-1}}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n {(-1)^{k+1} \frac{k+1}{2^k}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{k}{2^{k-1}} -\sum_{k=1}^n \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\\
&=-\frac{s_n}{2} -\frac{-1/2-(-1/2)^{n+1}}{1-(-1/2)}\\
&=-\frac{s_n}{2} +\frac{1-(-1/2)^n}{3},
\end{align}
so $s_n + a_{n+1} = a_1 + f(s_n)$ becomes
$$s_n + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n+1}{2^n} = -1 -\frac{s_n}{2} +\frac{1-(-1/2)^n}{3},$$
which implies that
$$s_n 
= \frac{2}{3}\left((-1)^n \frac{n+1}{2^n} -1 +\frac{1-(-1/2)^n}{3}\right)
= \frac{2}{9}\left((3n+2)\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n -2\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take case (a). Your sum and $f(s_n)$ is:

$\begin{align*}
  s_n
    &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} (-1)^k \frac{k}{2^{k - 1}} \\
  f(s_n)
    &= \sum_{2 \le k \le n + 1} (-1)^k \frac{k}{2^{k - 1}} \\
    &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} (-1)^{k + 1} \frac{k + 1}{2^k} \\
    &= \frac{-1}{2} \left(
                      \sum_{1 \le k \le n} (-1)^k \frac{k}{2^{k - 1}}
                        + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} (-1)^k \frac{1}{2^{k - 1}}
                   \right) \\
    &= \frac{-1}{2} \left(
                       s_n
                         + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} (-1)^k \frac{1}{2^{k - 1}}
                   \right) 
\end{align*}$

I'm sure you can take it from here.

Critical step is to transform the sum for $2 \le k \le n + 1$ into something involving $1 \le k \le n$ (shift indices) and then massage into an expression with the original coefficients. If any leftovers are easy to handle, you are done.